# Is Views are for SQL Select statement or for any other statement?

Tags: sql-server

are we using SQL Server Views for only Getting(SELECT) the Results or is there any other operations can be performed by using VIEWS.

My Question is i am Trying to Insert some New Records into my table by using Views, is it possible to do this operation by using this Views.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Comment: Ever tried to - ah - RTFM? Like the documentation. Like the create view statement, which is quite clear. YOu have a choice to make - either get used to read documentation, or never be a good programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, insert, update or delete using a `View`. From MSDN:

> You can modify the data of an underlying base table through a view, in
>   the same manner as   you modify data in a table by using UPDATE,
>   INSERT and DELETE statements or by using the bcp utility and BULK INSERT statement.

However, there are restrictions on how you can actually do this. You can read the details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). In short, the view must only reference columns from one base table, must not contain any computed or derived columns and must not contain grouping clauses.

Answer (score -2):

No, a view is a "virtual table", so you can't execute operations like insert and update.
You have to apply the changes into the original table then the view will reflect the changes.

[View](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)

If you are using MS SQL Server, you can use "Stored Procedure". Or similar in other DBMS.

Comment: Actually you can UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE data through a view, with some limitations of course, but you can.